# YouTube embed AirPlay UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, youtube, airplay

I am developing a video application which contains a lot of video from different sources. One of the options in the application has to be to play videos through airplay on a TV.

For displaying YouTube video in my application I am using YTPlayerView, which is an objective-C helper for the YouTube API.

My question is: is there an option or param I can pass so the YouTube video can also be played through Airplay? I couldn't find anything useful on Internet.

Comment: Have you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In `- (BOOL)loadWithPlayerParams:(NSDictionary *)additionalPlayerParams` in `YTPlayerView.m` ([line 617](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/blob/master/Classes/YTPlayerView.m#L617)), add:

```
self.webView.mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay = YES;
```

right before you `return YES`.