# AirPlay View in YTPlayerView doesn't appear

Tags: ios, airplay, mpvolumeview, ytplayerview

I'm using **YTPlayerView** (YouTube helper library) in my iOS application and according to requirements, I've made **custom controls** for airplay, share, play etc. For that I've hidden the default controls of YTPlayer using "**control**" tag.

The problem I'm facing is that, when I play video via airplay on some other media (e.g. appleTV, air server), the default view of YTPlayerView saying "Streaming to ... " Doesn't appear.

I guess it's because I've hidden the default controls.
I want this view to appear on screen whenever user choose other route for video. Unfortunately I'm unable to find the solution. Is there any way to do this or any notification that's fired whenever user switches video route, so that I can place my custom view for that scenario.

Comment: Hai, I want to do same thing, Want to play youtube video on airplay . Please let me know if you got any solution....

Comment: Hi @Mitesh Khatri, 
i used YTPlayer and it has all the controls (including airplay button as well). And tapping that button, video is played on airplay (provided some airplay device is available)

I used airServer for this purpose.

Comment: airServer is the paid.

Comment: yes, but i'm using it for testing purpose, trial version. Otherwise, you'll have to use apple TV etc

Comment: Duplicate: [YouTube embed AirPlay UIWebView](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26872364/2415822)